# Devolver 2 valores de un array asociativo multidimensional

Tags: php

teniendo este array:

```
$materias= array (
        array("nombre"=>"Juan","Programacion"=>8,"Redes"=>7,"Dise&ntildeo Web"=>10,"Conectividad"=>9,"Idiomas"=>8),

array("nombre"=>"Sofia","Programacion"=>9,"Redes"=>10,"Dise&ntildeo Web"=>6,"Conectividad"=>8,"Idiomas"=>7),

array("nombre"=>"Santiago","Programacion"=>10,"Redes"=>10,"Dise&ntildeo Web"=>9,"Conectividad"=>7,"Idiomas"=>9),

array("nombre"=>"Maria","Programacion"=>11,"Redes"=>12,"Dise&ntildeo Web"=>10,"Conectividad"=>9,"Idiomas"=>10),

array("nombre"=>"Damian","Programacion"=>7,"Redes"=>9,"Dise&ntildeo Web"=>10,"Conectividad"=>6,"Idiomas"=>6),
);
```

Deseo obtener la máxima nota por materia y mostrar a que alumno corresponde. Probé con `array_columns` y `max` y obtuve la nota máxima pero no logro que muestre junto a eso el nombre de a quién corresponde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vas por buen camino, esta es una solución rápida, sin validaciones adicionales en caso que el array esté vacio o no exista la clave, tampoco especificaste como vas a manejar cuando dos o más alumnos tienen la misma nota y esta es la máxima, así que esa parte la puedes completar:

```
function getBestStudent($materias, $materia)
{
    $notasMateria = array_column($materias, $materia);
    arsort($notasMateria);
    $resultado = 'Estudiante: ' . $materias[key($notasMateria)]['nombre'] . '<br>';
    $resultado .= 'Materia: ' . $materia . ' Nota: ' . $notasMateria[key($notasMateria)]; 

    return $resultado;
}

// En este caso para hallar la mejor nota (y estudiante) en Programacion
echo getBestStudent($materias, 'Programacion');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. 
No me queda claro igual que hace la primer linea $resultado

Comment: Simplemente obtengo la primera clave (esta ha sido reiniciada en el arsort) del arreglo y luego obtengo el nombre correspondiente. Puedes ver más detalles en la documentación de `key` de php.